# Heigth of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

i want to add two imageViews in one layout, images i will set from galery (diferent size of image).Defaut images- all is ok. But when i set image from galery (image one)-  a get a lot free space (image two)
[image: default images]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t55Uc.jpg):[image: when i add picture from galery - a get a lot free space]

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exrcise name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_exrcise_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Image"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RadioGroup

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_anime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:text="anime" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_static"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                    android:text="static" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image_one"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_apply_oval_new" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image_two"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_apply" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_set_image_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_set_image_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Muscle group"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_muscle_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tecnique"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_tecnique"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_save_exercise"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SAVE" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you please explain more what is the problem and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: look at image two. I didn't what to have that clear space( question mark)

Comment: what do you want there that will replace the empty space? also, can you please show the entire xml/code that causes it?

Comment: image one - there are default images, when i add image from galery the result - image two.I want to have like first picture when i add image from galery. Ok, a add it now.

Comment: the image can be captured using ddms rather than with camera

Comment: it two ways to set images: camera or galery, but it is not problem of this.

Comment: I see you have set one of the inner `LinerLayout`'s height to be `fill_parent`. Can you try with `wrap_content` ?

Comment: i tryed, the same result

Comment: Hi, Kostya. The problem is not described clearly. So, if I correctly understood your problem, if you set default links to images for iv_image_one and iv_image_two via android:src="@drawable/btn_apply" the screen looks like first screenshot. But if you provide the images by using gallery, you have the result like on screenshot #2. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

It worked for a similar problem i've had some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the height of both the problematic linearLayout and the imageView to wrap_content?

also, have you tried to set a weight (to 1) to the problematic linearLayout and then set its height to 0px ?